# Solr: import tab delimited file with multilines field

Tags: solr

I have a tab delimited file and one of the fields of this file has multi lines free text value, enclosed in quotes, like this sample line:

```
10,john,"this is 
an example of
multiline value...",30,house,10
```

I am using this line to import such file in Solr 4.4:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/update/csv?commit=true&separator=%09&escape=\&stream.file=/path/myfile.tsv'
```

but it fails as it cannot recognise the multilines field so it is not able to proceed with the import process.

How can I make the import working?

Comment: Have you tried using the encapsulator parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Matt Pearce suggested, adding `&encapsulator="` solves the problem.